# Laplacian sharpening - grey image as result

Tags: python, image-processing, scipy

As many people before me, I am trying to implement an example of image sharpening from Gonzalez and Woods "Digital image processing" book.

I create a negative Laplacian kernel (-1, -1, -1; -1, 8, -1; -1, -1,-1) and convolve it with the image, then subtract the result from the original image. (I also tried taking positive Laplacian (1, 1, 1; 1, -8, 1; 1, 1, 1) and adding it to the image). On each stage I perform fitting the results into the (0, 255) range, the normalized Laplacian looks nice and grey as it is supposed.

```
import matplotlib.cm as cm
import scipy.misc
import scipy.ndimage.filters

#Function for plotting abs:
pic_n = 1
def show_abs(I, plot_title):
    plt.title(plot_title)
    plt.tight_layout()
    plt.axis('off')
    plt.imshow(abs(I), cm.gray)

#Reading the image into numpy array:
A = scipy.misc.imread('moon1.jpg', flatten=True)

plt.figure(pic_n)
pic_n += 1
show_abs(A, 'Original image')

A          -= np.amin(A) #map values to the (0, 255) range
A          *= 255.0/np.amax(A)

#Kernel for negative Laplacian
kernel      = np.ones((3,3))*(-1)
kernel[1,1] = 8

#Convolution of the image with the kernel:
Lap         = scipy.ndimage.filters.convolve(A, kernel)

#Laplacian now has negative values in range (-255, 255):
print('L', np.amax(Lap), np.amin(Lap))

plt.figure(pic_n)
pic_n += 1
show_abs(Lap, 'Laplacian')

#Map Laplacian to the (0, 255) range:
Lap        -= np.amin(Lap)
Lap        *= 255.0/np.amax(Lap)
print('L', np.amax(Lap), np.amin(Lap))

plt.figure(pic_n)
pic_n += 1
show_abs(Lap, 'Normalized Laplacian')

A         += Lap #Add negative Laplacian to the original image

print('A', np.amax(A), np.amin(A))
A          -= np.amin(A)
A          *= 255.0/np.amax(A)
print('A', np.amax(A), np.amin(A))

plt.figure(pic_n)
pic_n += 1
show_abs(A, 'Laplacian filtered img')

plt.show()
```

### Original image:

[image: Original image]

### Results:

[image: Results]

The problem is that the final sharpened image looks faded and grey. I tried doing histogram equalization to make it more contrasting, but the result was weird. I thought about applying gamma-correction, but I don't like the voluntary choice of the gamma coefficient.

It seems there must be an easy and convenient way of bringing the image back to the original dynamic range. I would appreciate ideas and comments on the code. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to me that part of the problem has to do with how you are rescaling `Lap`. I don't think you want to subtract the minimum first - sharpening should decrease the intensity of some pixels as well as increasing that of others. You may also wish to play around with the scaling factor you multiply `Lap` by in order to control the degree of sharpening (255 might be too extreme).

The reason the background looks grey in the final image is probably because after adding the negative Laplacian there will be pixels in the moon that are darker than the background (the magnitude of the Laplacian in this part of the image will be greater since it contains more local structure). This means that you do your rescaling the background pixels will map to some value > 0. If you don't subtract the min from `Lap` then these darker pixels would have negative values, so you could then clip the pixel values in the resulting image such that they are all > 0. That way you will end up with a pure black background.

Comment: Hi, thank you for answering!
Do you mean I should add Laplacian with negative values to the image at first, and after that do the scaling? Or should I rescale Laplacian to some interval between 0 and 255 - if yes, how to chose it to certainly make the background black?

Comment: I would scale the Laplacian (still containing negative values), add it to the image, and then possibly truncate the resulting array so that all of the pixel values are greater than zero.

Comment: Thank you, that helped a lot, but I still can't undestand how it is working :( I got your idea about playing with the Laplacian scaling factor. And the background stays pure black now, but the higher the sharpening factor - the darker the image becomes. What I have: 1) scale the original image to (255.0, 0.0) 2) take the (-1, -1, -1; -1, 8, -1; -1, -1,-1) kernel and convolve it with the image. The result 'Lap' has values in range (1151.0, -1166.0).

Comment: 3) scale Lap according to the desired sharpening factor by multiplying it by 'factor/np.amax(Lap)', for the factor = 100 Lap lies in range (100.0, -101.303). 4) add up image and Lap. I expect the resulted sharpened image to lie in (355.0, -101.303) range, however, it happens to be in (350.917, -81.06) - why??

Comment: 5) taking absolute value of the result gives the sharpened image with the black background, because, as you have stated, the background should have the minimum value, 'abs' scales the sharpened image into (350.917, 0.0) range. The resulting image looks sharpened, but dark - probably still incorrectly scaled.

Comment: In order to see a value as high as 355 in the result, there would need to be a pixel whose value in the input image was 255, and where the value of the scaled Laplacian was also its maximum value of 100. There's no guarantee that the image will contain a pixel where these are both be true, so it's not surprising that you don't see a maximum pixel value of 355. The same is also true for the opposite extreme. Instead of taking the abs I would just clip the values so that negative pixel values map to zero. You could use `np.clip(A, 0, None)` or `np.clip(A, 0, 255)` .

Comment: Your explanation made it absolutely clear, thank you again! :)

Answer (score 3):

Returning to the same task two years later I refined the code as follows:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import scipy.misc
import scipy.ndimage.filters

# Function for plotting abs:
pic_num       = 1
def show_abs(I, plot_title, pic_num):
    plt.figure(pic_num)
    plt.title(plot_title)
    plt.tight_layout()
    plt.axis('off')
    plt.imshow(abs(I), plt.cm.gray)
    return pic_num+1

# Reading of the image into numpy array:
A0           = scipy.misc.imread('moon1.jpg', flatten=True)
# Map values to the (0, 255) range:
A0           = (A0 - np.amin(A0))*255.0 /(np.amax(A0)-np.amin(A0)) 

# Kernel for negative Laplacian:
kernel      = np.ones((3,3))*(-1)
kernel[1,1] = 8

# Convolution of the image with the kernel:
Lap        = scipy.ndimage.filters.convolve(A0, kernel)

#Map Laplacian to some new range:
ShF         = 100                   #Sharpening factor!
Laps        = Lap*ShF/np.amax(Lap) 

# Add negative Laplacian to the original image:
A           = A0 + Laps 
# Set negative values to 0, values over 255 to 255:
A = np.clip(A, 0, 255)

# Image the result:
pic_num = show_abs(Laps, 'Scaled Laplacian', pic_num)
pic_num = show_abs(A, 'Sharpened image', pic_num)
plt.show()
```

So both comments to the code above were true: I should not have rescaled the Laplacian, and fitting the sharpened image into (0, 255) by numpy-clipping gives a nice result. No OpenCV and histogram equalization needed so far.

Answer (score 1):

After correcting the code as **ali_m** advised, I apply local histogram equalization - it slows down the code and also adds dependency on the OpenCV library, but the resulting image looks fine.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.cm as cm
import scipy.misc
import scipy.ndimage.filters
import cv2

#Function for plotting abs:
pic_n       = 1
def show_abs(I, plot_title):
    plt.title(plot_title)
    plt.tight_layout()
    plt.axis('off')
    plt.imshow(abs(I), cm.gray)

#Reading of the image into numpy array:
A0           = scipy.misc.imread('moon1.jpg', flatten=True)
A0          -= np.amin(A0)#map values to the (0, 255) range
A0          *= 255.0/np.amax(A0)
print('Img         ', np.amax(A0), np.amin(A0))
#>>> Img          255.0 0.0

#Kernel for negative Laplacian
kernel      = np.ones((3,3))*(-1)
kernel[1,1] = 8

#Convolution of the image with the kernel:
Lap        = scipy.ndimage.filters.convolve(A0, kernel)

#Laplacian now has negative values
print('Original Lap', np.amax(Lap), np.amin(Lap))
#>>> Original Lap 1151.0 -1166.0

#Map Laplacian to some new range:
Laps        = Lap*100.0/np.amax(Lap) #Sharpening factor!
print('Scaled Lap  ', np.amax(Laps), np.amin(Laps))
#>>> Scaled Lap   100.0 -101.303

plt.figure(pic_n)
pic_n += 1
plt.subplot(1,2,1)
show_abs(Lap, 'Laplacian')
plt.subplot(1,2,2)
show_abs(Laps, 'Scaled Laplacian')

A           = A0 + Laps #Add negative Laplacian to the original image

print('SharpImg    ', np.amax(A), np.amin(A))
#>>> SharpImg     350.917 -81.06

A = abs(A) #Get rid of negative values
print('SharpImg abs', np.amax(A), np.amin(A))

A           *= 255.0/np.amax(A)
print('SharpImg after scaling', np.amax(A), np.amin(A))
#>>> SharpImg abs 350.917 0.0

# Local Histogram Equalization with OpenCV:
A_cv2       = A
A_cv2       = A_cv2.astype(np.uint8)

tile_s0     = 4
tile_s1     = 4

clahe       = cv2.createCLAHE(clipLimit=1, tileGridSize=(tile_s0,tile_s1))
A_cv2       = clahe.apply(A_cv2)

plt.figure(pic_n)
pic_n += 1
plt.subplot(2,1,1)
plt.hist(A_cv2)
plt.title('Original Histogram')
plt.subplot(2,1,2)
plt.hist(A_cv2)
plt.title('Locally Equalized Histogram')

plt.figure(pic_n)
pic_n += 1
plt.subplot(1,3,1)
show_abs(A0, 'Original image')
plt.subplot(1,3,2)
show_abs(A, 'Laplacian filtered img')
plt.subplot(1,3,3)
show_abs(A_cv2, 'Local Hist equalized img')
plt.show()
```

[image: Results:]

Answer (score 1):

I recently also struggled with this a bit, until I realised, that the example in Gonzalez & Woods is done with Matlab, where it seems that the imshow-function truncates the double values (all values below 0 are set to 0 - all values above are set to 1).

So doing something like this, worked for me:

```
  imgfloat = L.astype(np.float32) / 255
  imgLaplacian = cv2.filter2D(imgfloat, cv2.CV_32F, self.sharpeningKernel)
  res = imgfloat - imgLaplacian
  res[res < 0.0] = 0.0
  res[res > 1.0] = 1.0

  res = (res * 255).astype(np.uint8)
```

With sharpeningKernel defined as

```
  self.sharpeningKernel = np.zeros((3,3),np.float32)
  self.sharpeningKernel[0,1] = 1.0
  self.sharpeningKernel[1,0] = 1.0
  self.sharpeningKernel[1,1] = -4.0
  self.sharpeningKernel[1,2] = 1.0
  self.sharpeningKernel[2,1] = 1.0
```